# JavaFX TabPane remove/removeAll does not work

Tags: javafx, tabpanel

Good day, I have a problem when trying to remove tab's from a TabPane in JavaFX.
First thing I do I pass an ArrayList of String's with selected tab names from the list to the method which suppose to delete the corresponding by name tabs from the TabPane:

```
removeBranch.setOnAction(e->{
            ArrayList<String>indexes=new ArrayList(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

            entryShifts.removeBranch(indexes);
            list.getItems().removeAll(indexes);

        });
```

Afterwards I try to delete them like this in the mentioned method:

```
public void removeBranch(ArrayList<String> branch){
           pane.getTabs().removeAll(branch);
    }
```

However it does not work, even if I do something like(Please notice I pass only the first name from the list):

```
public void removeBranch(ArrayList<String> branch){
        pane.getTabs().remove(branch.get(0));
    }
```

But if I do something like this, it works (here I only remove the first name from the ArrayList as well):

```
public void removeBranch(ArrayList<String> branch){
        pane.getTabs().forEach(i -> {
            if (i.getText().equals(branch.get(0))) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    pane.getTabs().remove(i);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

P.S the way I fixed it by looping through the ArrayList and passing each time a different name to the method:

```
indexes.forEach(i->{entryShifts.removeBranch(i);});

public void removeBranch(String branch){
        pane.getTabs().forEach(i -> {
            if (i.getText().equals(branch)) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    pane.getTabs().remove(i);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `pane.getTabs()` returns a list of `Tab`, and you are trying to find `String`s in it. You need a way to convert the strings (Tab names?) to the actual `Tab` nodes in the `TabPane`.

One such way is to have a `Map<String, Tab> map` which you initialize with the tab names and tabs, and then do something like:

```
List<Tab> tabs = branch.stream().map(map::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
pane.getTabs().removeAll(tabs);
```

Comment: well I managed to figure it out almost at the same time, but I fixed it in a different way. The way I fixed it I will add to my question.